# Sitecore Custom Data Provider doubles language versions?

Tags: sitecore

So lately I've been working on a Custom Data Provider for Sitecore and it's really neat and works pretty well until I encountered this:

[image: Double Languages]

As you can see I'm receiving double language versions. Even though the GetItemVersions of my DataProvider looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used to retrieve version and language information of given item.
/// </summary>
public override VersionUriList GetItemVersions(ItemDefinition itemDefinition, CallContext context)
{
    VersionUriList result = null;

    if (itemDefinition.ID == RootItem.RootId)
    {
        // Our root only has 1 version in 1 language.
        result = new VersionUriList { new VersionUri(LanguageManager.GetLanguage("en"), Version.First) };
    }
    else if (CanProcess(itemDefinition.ID))
    {
        // Snipped processing of own items
    }

    return result;
}
```

So this means that any item that I don't handle I return `null`. Has anyone seen this behaviour before and knows exactly where to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 29/04/2014**

Meanwhile I have found an even better way to cure this. In the configuration of a dataprovider you can determine which methods are available like so:

```
<sitecore>
    <dataProviders>
        <CustomDataProvider type="MyLib.Data.CustomDataProvider, MyLib">
            <disable>*</disable>
            <enable>GetChildIDs</enable>
            <enable>GetParentID</enable>
            <enable>GetItemDefinition</enable>
            <enable>GetItemVersions</enable>
            <enable>GetItemFields</enable>
        </CustomDataProvider>
    </dataProviders>
</sitecore>
```

---

For those who are running into the same issue as myself when following the guidelines of the [documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/developer/integrating%20external%20data%20sources/implementation/read-only%20sources.aspx):

They forgot to mention that when you integrate into an existing DB (like the master) that you need to override following method:

```
/// <summary>
/// We don't store any languages.
/// </summary>
public override LanguageCollection GetLanguages(CallContext context)
{
    return null;
}
```

Otherwise your dataprovider is somehow smart enough to return the languages and thereby supplying them 2 times effectively to Sitecore causing the issue displayed above. (which breaks TDS)

Answer (score 1):

I was having exactly the same problem. Override  GetItemVersions and GetLanguages fixed the problem.

```
public override VersionUriList GetItemVersions(ItemDefinition itemDefinition, CallContext context)
        {
            if (return true if the itemDefinition is a item from your db)
            {
                VersionUriList result = new VersionUriList();

                //Add versions on languages you want
                result.Add(LanguageManager.GetLanguage("nl"), Sitecore.Data.Version.First);
                result.Add(LanguageManager.GetLanguage("en"), Sitecore.Data.Version.First);

                return result;
            }
            //itemDefinition is a item from a sitecore db => return null (sc will handle versions of his items)
            return null;
        }
```

And override GetLanguages to return null as suggested